# Is it possible to set custom metadata (such as a tag) on files in Microsoft OneDrive for Business API?

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I want to know if it is possible to set arbitrary metadata on a file. Can I perform a search on a file with this metadata with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, One drive for business doesnt support any custom meta data or views. it is more or less just an windows folder but in the cloud.